# passing data by startActivityForResult() and startActivity() among activitis

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, start-activity

I am working on an application which has 3 activities: **A**, **B** and **C**.

The starting activity is **A** after that there is a button that goes to **B**, and also in **B** a button to go to **C**. In activity **C** I need to go back to **A** to get some data.

So my application runs like this:

> A -> B -> C -> A -> C

I am using

Between **A** and **B**:

```
StartActivity(intent);
```

Between **B** and **C**:

```
StartActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

But in activity **A** when I use

```
OnActivityResult(..);
```

it is not working as expected.

Can you please help me?

Comment: you are using startActivity for result in B and want to get result in A. That's wrong if you want to get result in A then startActivity in A and also get result in A.
And if you want to start C from B then use both these in B and then send the result to A.

Comment: @Darkie i did that but the thing is when i go from B to A using onbackpress button the changes that should only happen when getting back from C to A happens from B to A and i don't want that

Comment: how are you going from C to A? Through B?

Comment: @Adams you can override the onbackpress button and do what you want to do

Comment: @random i'm going from C to A, B is finished

Comment: How are you finishing B, inside B's OnActivityResult? If you're finishing B inside its OnActivityResult, which brings you to activity A, it doesn't mean that Activity A's OnActivityResult will get the result. For A's OnActivityResult to receive the result, Activity B should send result back to A since it was B which was called from A not C

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is :

> A -> B -> C -> A -> C

I am using

Between A and B:

StartActivity(intent);

Between B and C:

StartActivityForResult(intent,1);

> Now, when you exit Activity C, the callback comes to B
>
> B gets : `onActivityResult()`

So, please think and execute your logic this way